# How to handle duplicate values

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with 100k plus items.
I need to create a table with "best prices"

Most items have a unique supplier, however some can be sourced from 2 or 3 different suppliers but have the same Manufacturer Part Number [MPN].

To find the duplicate values I have used:

```
In (SELECT [MPN] FROM [Main Data] As Tmp GROUP BY [MPN] HAVING Count(*)>1 )
```

How do I handle the duplicate records? For each duplicated [MPN] I want to select the record that is both in stock and has lowest price?

Table has fields:
[EAN], [MPN], [Inventory Number] - this field has a unique supplier suffix, [Name], [Cost], [Quantity]

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this:

```
SELECT M1.MPN, M1.[Name], M2.QTY, Max(M1.Cost) as MaxCost, Min(M1.Cost) as MinCost
FROM [Main Data] M1
INNER JOIN (SELECT [MPN], Sum(1) as QTY FROM [Main Data] GROUP BY [MPN] HAVING Count(*)>1 ) M2
   ON M1.MPN = M2.MPN
GROUP BY M1.MPN, M1.[Name]
```

This will give you the quantity in stock and highest price, as well as the lowest price for each item.  Feel free to remove those other fields if you find them useless.

Comment: Thanks for you very quick response Johnny Bones. However I'm getting a Syntax error in FROM clause,  from the M2 after the HAVING Count(*)>1))?

Comment: Can you confirm that SELECT [MPN], Sum(1) as QTY FROM [Main Data] As Tmp GROUP BY [MPN] HAVING Count(*)>1  returns results?

Comment: Yes it does. Shows I have an issue with blank MPN's, but I'll tackle that later!

Comment: I'm not sure if this will do anything but in the middle of that SQL statement it says "FROM [Main Data] As Tmp GROUP BY".  That "As Tmp" shouldn't be there, it's never referenced.  Try removing it, you don't need it and it may be confusing the compiler.

Comment: Should the "As Tmp" be "As M2"? This results in syntax error in Join operation. Removing the "As tmp" still has the FROM clause error.

Comment: You don't need to alias [Main Data] as anything, because that whole SELECT statement gets aliased as M2.  For a test, just remove that whole part of the query and replace it with "[Main Table]" so the line reads "INNER JOIN [Main Table] M2".  Let me know if you get an error or not, and don't worry about the data.  Actually, you're gonna have to comment out M2.QTY from the very first line as well because that field won't exist in this test.

Comment: The mystery deepens...  OK, I edited my answer, give that a shot and let me know.

Comment: Now problem with executing query not include specified expression 'QTY' as part of aggregate function. However I will be away for a couple of days now, so thanks for your help, please understand if I don't get back to you until then.

Comment: Johnny back now - To clarify what I need is a query that will list all unique MPNs only and where there are duplicates available, the lowest priced that is in stock is selected.

Comment: Found solution SELECT [Main Data].MPN, Min([Main Data].[Quantity]) AS [MinOfQuantity], Min([Main Data].[Cost]) AS [MinOfCost]
FROM [Main Data]
GROUP BY [Main Data].MPN
HAVING ((([Main Data].MPN) Is Not Null) AND ((Min([Main Data].[Quantity]))>0) AND ((Min([Main Data].[Cost]))>0));